# geom_smooth option missing ggplot from python

Tags: python-2.7, python-ggplot

I am trying to make plot using ggplot in python. When I try to run, I get an error"

`ggplot(data,aes(x='Average Credit Card Transaction',y='response'))+\
geom_smooth(se=False,span=0.2)+xlab("Average Credit Card Transaction")+\
ylab('Response')+\
ggtitle('Partial Dependence Plot \n Response Vs Average Credit Card transactions')`

`NameError: name 'geom_smooth' is not defined`

Everything else works. Was that a bug which was fixed in later versions?

Answer (score 2):

You can try `stat_smooth` instead (shown with `mtcars` dataset):

```
from ggplot import *
ggplot(mtcars, aes('mpg', 'qsec')) + \
  geom_point(colour='red') + \
   stat_smooth(colour='blue', se=False, span=0.2) + \
   ggtitle("mtcars stat_smooth")
```

[image]